# How to terminate specific request running in flask server?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I've a flask server and for every request I'm starting a new thread. Each request takes about an hour to complete. Here if I want to terminate specific running request after 10-20 minutes due to some reason how can I do it? This must not close the server or affect other running requests.

I want something line an id returned from request/thread that I can store inside database and use later to kill that particular process.

Comment: You can't kill a thread safely. You'd need a separate process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy flask server by a WSGI such as gunicorn. It 'll handle request to server by your configure.

The param help your case is `--timeout 600` https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout